# Does the scim spec define how to specify a filter for nested objects?

Tags: scim, scim2

If I have data that looks like this:

```
{
  "source": {
    "id": "someStr",
    "type": "someTypeStr",
    "someObj": {
      "objId": "someStr",
      "numField": 2
    }
  },

  "destination": {
    "id": "someStr",
    "type": "someTypeStr",
    "someObj": {
      "objId": "someStr",
      "numField": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Filtering works fine when we want to filter someting like `source.id PR` or `destination.type co "something"`. However, I'm not sure what the proper scim way is to filter on the "someObj" field within? I can't seem to find anything in the spec about this, is there a accepted way to represent a filter like `source.someObj.numField eq 2`?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your example - are source and destination complex attributes?

Comment: Yes they are. I'm probably not explaining this great, but we have a dataset where each datapoint consists of something like above, where is has a "source" object that has several attributes including attributes like "someObj" which themselves are attribute, and another "destination" object with the same attributes. So we have an api that takes a scim filter string to return filtered results. One way we'd like to filter is to say `source.someObj.objId co "something"`. From what I know, it seems like a scim filter is generally in the form of `field.attribute [operation] [value]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not defined in the spec because it is not allowed. Complex attributes cannot have sub-attributes that are themselves complex attributes. See: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7643#section-2.3.8

> > A complex attribute MUST NOT contain sub-attributes
> > that have sub-attributes (i.e., that are complex).

The filter rules/syntax do not account for this because it is not possible in SCIM.